# MVC3 Displaying different fields in View depending on value of property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
if field3 = 1, html.labelfor(field2)
else html.labelfor(field1)
```

What's the best way to do this?  Should I have logic in my viewModel, or can I just throw some code into the view to perform the check?

Comment: Depends on what the problem is.
It might be logical to use different views and view models? it might not.
You could do it in the view if it is presentation specific but that is generally something to avoid if you want to re-use the view elsewhere.

Since your using the labelfor helpers I presume you may want to use the Display attributes too ? not just use the class' property name directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain why you want to do this?

But here goes:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => ((field3 == 1) ? m.field2 : m.field1) )%>
```